# What is the difference between "ventumi" and "aerumi"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between *aerumi* and *ventumi*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PIV definitions:

- *[aerumi](http://vortaro.net/#aerumi)*: *Elmetadi al la aero, por sanigi aŭ forigi haladzojn* ("to air out")
- *[ventumi](http://vortaro.net/#ventumi)*: *Refreŝigi, movante la aeron al iu* ("to fan")